# Audio file is not playing with iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I am trying to play audio file in my iphone app.I have used this code

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

 NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *musicPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"audioSample" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath];
    NSError *error= [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Domain" code:0 userInfo:nil];

    AVAudioPlayer *aplayer= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:&error];
    aplayer.delegate = self;
    [aplayer play];
```

But will running this app i am getting this error.Can anyone please help me to solve this.I am not getting that why this error is occurring.

```
System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-08-03 10:12:07.330 SampleAudioCode[591:12003] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-08-03 10:12:07.330 SampleAudioCode[591:12003] Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory B8A063B5-2F3D-444A-88CB-D0B8F1B22042 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0xdc50f50 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Thank you for your answer..

Comment: your code have no issue see my answer as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the AVAudio frameworks when using the iOS simulator only. Testing on actual hardware (an iPad 2 & iPad 1, in my case) does not produce these same errors

This error is just console noise from a System framework, you should ignore it, it doesn't affect you. If your app is crashing or failing to play the real reason is elsewhere.

```
and please also add CoreFoundation framwork.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.I will try this code with device. and i have already added your suggested framework.Do you think this code may create any problem with iphone or ipod??

Comment: No this is just simulator issue I have tested it but don't find any issue with it. :)

Comment: can you tell me how get the volume detail and change the volume?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Add The AVFoundation Framework

For that follow this Step

- Expand the Targets branch in the Groups & Files panel of the project
- Control-click or right-click the AudioPlayer item
- Choose Add > Existing Frameworks…
- Click the + button at the bottom left beneath Linked Libraries
- Choose AVFoundation.framework and click Add
- AVFoundation.framework will now be listed under Linked Libraries.
  Close the window

Now in .h file Include this framework And Create instance of avaudio player

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and in interface section

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

Now in Your .M file Use this code where you want to play .mp3 file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but its not working for me..I have used it but still error is not solved...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Useful for AudioPlayer...

```
-(void)play
{
    [audioPlayer stop];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[soundArry objectAtIndex:pageNo.currentPage]] ofType:@"mp3"]]; 

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];


}
```

soundArry is My SoundArray.
pageNo is My PageControl.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Useful for Audio play:

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audiofile" ofType:@"mp3"]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
if (audioPlayer == nil)
      NSLog([error description]);               
else 
     [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: I got this error. 

Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"

Comment: please change file path like :NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audiofile" ofType:@"mp3"];

Comment: Thank you for answer but I have change that but the same response.